# Add Elements To An Existing Array Bash

Tags: arrays, bash

I need to process some data in several steps.

I first create a list of managed policies in AWS and put that list into an array:

```
readarray -t managed_policies < <(aws iam list-attached-user-policies --user-name tdunphy  --output json --profile=company-nonprod | jq -r '.AttachedPolicies[].PolicyArn')
```

But then I need to add more information to that array later on in my script. My question is, can I use readarray to do this? Or do I just need to ammend the data to the list using the command such as:

```
managed_policies+=($(aws iam list-attached-group-policies --group-name grp-cloudops --profile=compnay-nonprod | jq -r '.AttachedPolicies[].PolicyArn'))
```

Comment: readarray is a  synonym for mapfile. Take a look at `help mapfile` and option `-O`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I suggest to use option `-O` to append to your array:

```
mapfile -t -O "${#managed_policies[@]}" managed_policies < <(aws ...)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also do this:

```
readarray -t managed_policies < <(aws ...)
readarray -t tmp < <(aws ...)
managed_policies+=("${tmp[@]}")
```

Comment: OP: But then I need to add more information to that array later on in my script  
<-- The above code **overwrites** the array with the new values. It does not **append** to the existing ones.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you could make the calls to `aws` immediately (and the example you give suggest you can, since both sets of arguments are hard-coded), you only need a single call to `readarray`. (The function is just some unnecessary refactoring.)

```
get_policies () {
  aws iam list-attached-user-policies --output json --profile company-nonprod "$@"
}

readarray -t managed_policies < <(
 { get_policies --user-name tdunphy
   get_policies --group-name grp-cloudops
 } | jq -r '.AttachedPolicies[].PolicyArn')
```

(Off-topic, but it's also possible you can omit the call to `jq` by using appropriate arguments to `aws` to adjust the output appropriately.)